# How do percentages in repeating-linear-gradient actually work?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

Hi,

I am trying to reproduce this pattern: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16oUN.jpg but I dont understand how percentages work. I tried a lot of combinations and this is the closest I can get:

```
 background:repeating-linear-gradient(#fafafa 0%, #e9e6d6 100%) repeat 0% 0%;
```

but not quite there yet. The acolor amounts are all wrong and I still dont understand the logics. What do percentages in the code mean exactly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The percentages are color-stops that declare where colors start. If you however have two color stops at the same percentage, then the transition is instant. [Here's a pretty good article on CSS3 gradients](https://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/).

For the reason why initial and ending colors do not require percentages:

> Note that the first and last color stops don't specify a location; because of that, values of 0% and 100% are automatically assigned to the first and last colors respectively. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_gradients).

Try out the code below:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right, /* direction of the linear-gradient */
      #181817, /* initial color */
      #181817 45%, /* immediate transition to #fafafa */
      #fafafa 45%, /* immediate transition to #fafafa */
      #fafafa 55%, /* immediate transition to #181817 */
      #181817 55% /* immediate transition to #181817 */
    );
}
```

Comment: I already knew that article but I dont quite get it yet. Why doesnt the first color get any percentage at all in your example?

Comment: It can be left off because it's implied that the initial color starts at 0%. In the example, `#181817` is equivalent to `#181817 0%`. If you edit it as such, you'll see that you will have the same result. This is also the case for if you have the last color without a percentage. It is assumed to be at the end or 100%.

Comment: can it be pixels instead of percentages?

Comment: Yes. It can be a percentage or any [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) value.

Comment: I think I kinda get it now. Thank you.